# can't find the resource which is in classpath while running the jar

Tags: java

I need to pass keystore path to a third party library as part of library constructor argument. I have kept keystore (samplecerts) in the classpath (src/main/resources)

I just added below line for testing purpose to see if file is really getting loaded and if I'm sending the correct path to third party

```
    InputStream in =  new FileInputStream(path);
```

Followed two approaches -

**Approach 1:** Get the absolute path -

```
  URL url =  MyTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("samplecerts");
  String path = url.getPath();
  System.out.println("Cert File Path:" +path);
  InputStream in =  new FileInputStream(path);
```

Got below error

```
 /usr/local/java/bin/java -cp my-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.sample.MyTest
 Cert File Path:file:/home/abc/my-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/samplecerts
   Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/abc/my-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/samplecerts (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at com.sample.MyTest.main(MyTest.java:33)
```

**Approach 2:** Give the file name which is in classpath under (src/main/resources/)

```
String path = "samplecerts";
System.out.println("Cert File Path:" +path);
InputStream in =  new FileInputStream(path);
```

Got the below error -

```
/usr/local/java/bin/java -cp my-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.sample.MyTest
Cert File Path:samplecerts
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: samplestore (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
 at com.sample.MyTest.main(MyTest.java:33)
```

In eclipse, it works fine if run as java program. What could be the reason for these errors and how to get it working?

Comment: The resource is inside the jar. A resource inside a jar file is not a file on the file system. So you can't possibly use a **File**InputStream to read it. Class.getResourceAsStream() returns a stream. Why use a FileInputStream, instead of that stream? If the library expects a file path, and not a stream, then 1. it's badly designed, 2. You need to have the file on the file system, not inside the jar.

Comment: In eclipse you have access to the source and build folders so it has the ability to find the non-jar'ed resource.  When run externally from eclipse it has only the jar'ed version of everything and thus finds the resource within the jar.  As the previous comment states, since this resource doesn't physically exist on disk you can't use FileInputStream to read it.

Comment: @JBNizet I wanted to avoid having file in file system since it's not going to change and don't want deployment script taking care of putting the file in file system. I agree with your point that third part API should have given an option of sending stream but is there getting the file path by having it in jar?

Comment: You can still read the resource from the jar and write it to a temp file, then pass the path of the temp file to the library, but it's a hack.

Answer (score 0):

If your samplecerts for example is located under `/org/whatever/security/` within you jar, then you could load it like this:

```
final String myPath = "/org/whatever/security/samplecerts";
InputStream myCerts = getClass().getResourceAsStream(myPath);
```